# Alternatives to loop reading byte-by-byte from a socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I use

```
char readByte = (char) classServerConnectionSingletonSocketDataInputStream.readByte();
```

in a loop.
Is there in Java an alternative to read all the already available bytes in the input stream?

For example, in Php I use

```
$socketread = @socket_read($arrayclients[$arrayclientkey]["socket"],1024);
```

and it reads up all the available bytes up to 1024 bytes.

Comment: How about just using [read](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/datainputstream_read.htm)?

Comment: You provide almost no information but every class that extends from `InputStream` has bulk read methods like [`read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,int,int)) and [`readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()). What's wrong with them?